# For any $n\in \mathbb Z^{>0}$, $End_{Ab}(\mathbb Z_n)\cong \mathbb Z_n$ as a ring. In general $End_{Ab}(R)\cong R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Note that, our ring is unitial, but doesnot have to be commutative.

My attempt for the first question:

We have a map in general that $R\to End_{Ab}(R)$ maps $r\mapsto \phi_r: R\to R\\\quad \quad \quad \quad a\mapsto ra$ which is **injective**.

And I can show that $End_{Ab}(\mathbb Z_n)$ has also $n$ many elements. So they are indeed isomorphic as rings.

In general we also have that $R\to End_{Ab}(R)$ maps $r\mapsto \varphi_r: R\to R\\\quad \quad \quad \quad a\mapsto ar$ whic is **surjective**.

So in general to say $End_{Ab}(R)\cong R$, if $R$ is commutative we are done.

Question: If R is not commutative what conditions we force to get $End_{Ab}(R)\cong R$ ?

Comment: What is $End_{Ab}$?

Comment: endomorphisms of the abelian group structre of R

Comment: $End_{left \ R-module}(R)\cong R$ through the map $f\mapsto f(1)$. Obviously $End_{group}(R)$ can be larger, try $R=\Bbb{Z}^2$ so that $End_{group}(R)\cong M_2(\Bbb{Z})$.